# Command line Questions in R

Tags: command-line, r, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am building an user input interface in R.

onload of the program, I would like like to ask the user what their preferences are according to a set of 6 fields.  This will then be used as a comparison tool for the rest of the program.

e.g.,

```
>ThisProgram  
>"Hello, on a scale of 1 to 10, how much would you say you rate the outdoors in your trips?    Enter a 10 for very important, and a 1 for not important at all.   
>7  
>"Great. on a scale of 1 to 10, how much would you say you rate the Family Friendly in your  trips?  Enter a 10 for very important, and a 1 for not important at all. 
>2
  .
  .
  .
  and so on...
```

how would I get R to ask the user a question, and then store the response in a vector?

Answer (score 5):

See `?readline`

```
> x <- readline("What is your name? ")
What is your name? Josh
> x
[1] "Josh"
```

Comment: See also: `menu` for multiple choice selections and the `gWidgets*` packages for graphical user interfaces.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: Or also `tcltk` and `RGtk2` packages for generating GUIs.

Comment: Nico: gWidgets* wrap around `tcltk` and `RGtk2`.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: oh, I did not know, always though it was a 3rd option (my bad, never really looked at it! :D)

Comment: Wow... you guys are awesome.  I'll be checking these out!