# How to read user input in the console window?

Tags: r, input, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command line Questions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454969/command-line-questions-in-r)

Say, if I enter a string into the console, how can I get R to recognise that it is a string (or whatever type of data I entered) and store it into `x`?

Because what I want to do is: if the user inputs 'hungry', then R should recognise this string 'hungry' and run a particular function. Is that possible?

Comment: tip: Since you're a newbie, most questions that might come up for you have already been asked on this forum. type in `[r] <search-term>` to find an earlier question that contains the answer you need. This one will likely be closed up shortly.

Comment: Since we're giving advice to new folks, please to take note of how I edited your question. Putting some effort into making your question look nice will help prevent users from down voting or closing it.

Comment: voting to close, but guessing one possible wrinkle here: if you read the string `"hungry"` and store it in a variable `x` but want to run the function `hungry()`, you need to use `get(x)` to retrieve the function called `hungry` ... e.g. `x <- "hungry"; f <- get(x); f(1,2)` will give the same output as `hungry(1,2)`